# List of images and video files in one view with one highlighted element shown bigger

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create an activity in which the user can see a list of image and video files with the selected item of the list shown in a bigger view than the unselected ones. This looks a bit like the screen of Instagram when you want to upload an image.

[Instagram upload layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6dZv.jpg)

What I want however, is that the user is able to swipe (grey arrow) on the bigger view so that the next element of the list is then shown in that view. Also, when the user clicks on one of the elements (the smaller circles under the big view), the related file should be displayed in the bigger square view.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmuFY.png)

Is it possible to do this with one RecyclerView?

Thank you!

Comment: We were trying to find the cleanest way to do this. Now we tried it with two different RecyclerViews, each containing the same datasets, and manually handling all clicks and swipes, but we feel there must be a better way to do this..

Comment: @Jan It's amazing to me that almost every article/blog on RecyclerViews has its focus on creating a list, but none on saving the list. It does no good to create a beautifully crafted/valuable list (say a big list of songs I want to download) and then have the list literally be destroyed if I navigate away from the list with the single press of the back button. Why wouldn't saving state code be a requirement for creating every RecyclerView list just like the other requirements: the adapter, the layoutmanager, onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and getItemCount?  What am I missing here?

Comment: How would you save the state of a RecyclerView? Adapters and layout managers are not saved, but created every time when needed, no?